# Accessing an array of colorPicker values in a loaded swf in flex

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, swfloader

I have a flex application that dynamically loads swfs and I want to to use a set of color pickers in an external component within the application to determine a color array in the loaded swf.

I figured that I can use a new array of the colorPickers, i.e.

```
public var colors:Array  = new Array [ cp01.selectedColor, cp02.selectedColor, cp03.selectedColor, cp04.selectedColor, cp05.selectedColor]
```

Is it possible for the swf to read the Array if it's set up like that? If so what would I put into the swf to get it? If not what do I need to do?

Comment: do you need to access current colorpicker value from that array, or just to save the state it had when the array was created?

Comment: Current value, in case it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an array of pickers and use it as follows:

```
    private var pickers:Array  = new Array [ cp01, cp02, cp03, cp04, cp05];
    public function getColorByPickerNumber(n:int):int {
        return pickers[n] ? pickers[n]['selectedColor'] : 0;
    }
```

you can also use [binding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc9.html)

Comment: How do I access the variable from the swf? For instsance if I currently have the array as `var desColors:Array = [0x66CCFF,0x663300,0x996600,0xCCFFFF,0x0099FF]` how would I define the cp1CurrentColor. I tried replacing the colors within the brackets with with the cp1CurrentColor variable and that did nothing.